# On the Integral Representation of Greens Functions

Tags: fourier-transform, greens-functions, klein-gordon-equation

In Birrell & Davies book "QFT in Curved Spacetime" the authors discuss in chapter 2.7 that all Greens Functions (which are the vacuum expectation values of products of fields) can be written as
$$
\mathcal{G}(x,x')=(2\pi)^{-n}\int d^n k\frac{\exp
\left[ i\vec{k}{\left(\vec{x}-\vec{x}'\right)-ik^0(t-t')} \right]}{(k^0)^2-|\vec{k}|^2-m^2}
$$

The authors don't really explain why this statement is true. As I remember, this is a general statement about Green's functions for scalar fields in Minkowski spacetime. How can we see that this is true?

This should also satisfy equation (2.73) which reads
$$
\left(\Box_x+m^2\right)\mathcal{G}(x,x')=0, \qquad x\neq x', \tag{2.73}
$$
but if we substitute it in we get $\left(\Box_x+m^2\right)\mathcal{G}(x,x')=\omega^2\mathcal{G}(x,x')$. What am I missing here?

**Edit**

The given form does indeed satisfy the equation. The substitution actually gives
$$
\left(\Box_x+m^2\right)\mathcal{G}(x,x')=(-\omega^2+k^2+m^2)\mathcal{G}(x,x')=0
$$

Comment: The $\Box_x=(\partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu})_x$ is the d'Alembertian operator, where with $x$ I label the spacetime point $x$ and not the position (3-vector) $\vec{x}$ (as opposed to the spacetime point $x'$). I am saying that because $(\Box_x+m^2)\mathcal{G}(x,x')$ shouldn't result in $\sim \omega^2$, but in $\sim k^2$, where $k$ is the momentum fourvector, instead ;)